# Constant of Variation Word Problem.. check if my answer is correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please check if my answer is correct

The current I varies directly as the electromotive force E and inversely as the resistance R. If in a system a current of 20 amperes flows through a resistance of 20 ohms with an electromotive force of 100 volts, find the current that 150 volts will send through the system

So my answer is 
I=kE/R
20=k100/20
400=k100
K=4

Find the Current when 150 volts flow
I=4*150/20
20I=600
I=30 ampheres
Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

I got 30 A as well, assuming the 20 Ω resistor is in parallel with the rest of the system with resistance R.